# how to get string value from a method in class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class where I have a method that is creating a connection string.I want to access that connection string from other windows,but that isn't working.This is my code so far:

My main login is just calling the method from a class on a button click

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 kl = new Class1();
        kl.SQLCon(textBox, textBox_Copy);

    }
```

My class looks like this:

```
class Class1
{
    string user = string.Empty;
    string pass = string.Empty;
    private string ConString = string.Empty;

    public string User { get { return this.ConString; } set { this.ConString = value; } }

    public void SQLCon(TextBox tb1,TextBox tb2)
    {
        user = tb1.Text;
        pass = tb2.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Popuni sva polja");
            return;
        }
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "Manager";
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        builder.UserID = user;
        builder.Password = pass;

        try
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                if ((con != null && con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    ConString = builder.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Uspesno logovan!" + ConString);
                    Window1 win = new Window1();
                    win.ShowDialog();

                }

            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Now when from the Window1 I call the method to get ConString,I get nothing,blank.The problem is that it is not looking in the SQLCon for the string value,it is looking it as it is defined at the beggining of the class.
I can get this to work with this solution: before calling ShowDialog,I can have a string in the Window1, that I can pass this value, something like win.stringCon = ConString,and this works.But I want to be able to do this:

Window1 code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 myClass = new Class1();
        string conn = myClass.User;

        MessageBox.Show(conn);
    }
```

Comment: You are setting the field `ConString` which is what  `User` returns in the method `SQLCon`. But you don't call this method in your Window1-`button_Click`. Note: whenever you call the constructor `new Class1()` you will create a new instance of this class and all members have their default values.

Comment: sorry,that was I typo.I have edited it,but the result is the same.
Ok I get your input about new Class1(),but how can I get pass that?

Comment: You have to store the instance somewhere, for example as field, instead of always creating a new instance.

Comment: I know how to do that,before using the ShowDialog() I would pass the value to some string in the Window..I was hoping that I could do something like this...thank you for you time :)

Comment: I think what @TimSchmelter means is you should have a reference to your `Class1` instance, since you have used it before your button click it seems!? Creating a new instance has no connection string set until you call your `SQLCon` method.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: You can't do it the way I imagined. But here is what you can do.
You define a string (conString) in the Window1 that will be you connection string.And you put this line before you call win.ShowDialog():

mw.conString = conString;

This way you have the string in your new window.And with one line you can transport the value from Window1 to some other Window that you will open next.